# Vue-i18n translations in js file instead of json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

How to use `.js` file with translations instead of `.json`?

Changing:

`const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)`

to

`const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.js$/i)`

doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Can you create an example of what you're trying to do?  

You can import the locale file into Vue with a JS `import`

Comment: have you tried with locale[$i18n.locale] ?

Answer (score 1):

I found an aswer, it may be helpful for some in future. From vue-cli 3 edit root directory i18n.js file, function loadLocalMessages:

```
function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.js$/i)
  const messages = {}

  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)

    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key).default
    }
  })

  return messages
}
```

and `locales/en.js`

```
const translations = { /* translations here */ }
export default translations
```